# What exactly does firebase use when ordering Childs in firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]I was trying to use firebase database for a price filter feature, where prices are entered as Childs in a node, I figured they would automatically be entered by ascending numeric orders, but it seems like that is not always the case.[image]

For example as you see on the photo, 55 comes before 450, and 55,000 comes before 450,000, but somehow 5,500,000,000 comes after 45,000,000,000 even though it is a lower numeric value, is there a reason for this behavior?

Pls explain, Thank YOu.

Answer (score 1):

Keys in the Firebase Realtime Database are stored as strings. And in string comparison `2` comes after `11`, no matter how unintuitive that may be.

Since keys are stored as strings and you can't change that, the only solution is to change the format in which you store them. For example: if you store all values in a fixed length string and left-pad it with either zeroes or spaces, their alphabetical order will be the same as the numerical order.

For example:

```
00000000055
00000000450
00000055000
00000450000
05500000000
45000000000
```

Since you're using some really large numbers, it might also be worth to ensure Firebase interprets them as strings everywhere by prefixing them with an alphanumeric value, like:

```
"key00000000055"
"key00000000450"
"key00000055000"
"key00000450000"
"key05500000000"
"key45000000000"
```

Comment: Pls check the second photo i just added, it looks like 2 actually comes before 11 on the key order, and 3 comes before 22 , and so on, actually looks like firebase is pretty good with ordering the keys in ascending numeric value until it reaches 2147483648 , which also happens to be the max value you can set for int before android throws an "integer number too large" error.

Comment: Interesting. I guess is depends on how the console interprets the keys. In that case, I'd recommend  forcing it to use string keys by prefixing them (and still padding them with zeroes). So `"key 00000000055"`, `"key00000000450"`, etc.

Comment: This looks like an idiosyncracy in the console itself.  The ordering of the keys does not seem to follow either normal dictionary sort order nor normal numerical order.

Comment: Yeah, I have a feeling it reaches the end of the JavaScript `number` type at some point. Regardless though, I'd pick a key format that sorts consistently, which is what I described above.